# How to use Notification Manager to send messages weekly

Tags: android, eclipse, popup, message

I am making an application which will send popup messages in the notification bar of the user, these messages have them send agree to a date specified weekly depending on the day, for example every Monday of each week, as I do that in android eclipse? I need besides those messages arrive so the application is closed, now I have a database in sqlite with notifications have to do weekly. Thank You

Answer (score 0):

You can setup an alarm which should fire up a IntentService who in turn will fire up the notification. In the Service you can consult DB in order to decide to set a notification or not.

All this is done not in Eclipse but using Android API.

Yes, after alarm in configured, it will act despite of application running.

Comment: Can you link me an example please?, ty so much

Comment: "Read the docs, Luke!"
It is very clearly described in "Notifications" API guide how to use it; also please make a little self-training in Alarms and Services. I am convinced - you must educate yourself. I gave you the main direction, please try.

Comment: Mm ty for the help i guess

Comment: I can't guess your acronyms meaning. Would you be so kind to write full words? Thanks a lot in advance.